How to control the scaling/cropping of a background image
I created a new scene in Unity, dragged an image file, and scaled it to fit the screen size. Here is how it looks like in the Scene panel:

When I change the screen size, e.g. by switching to Simulator mode, the bird is outside the screen:

What can I do to ensure that, when the screen size changes, the background image also changes its size, so that the bird always remains within the screen boundaries? Something like this:


Have you made any effort to read the documentation or research this on the internet?

One way to set this up is to use a UI Canvas.
We'll set the "Canvas Scaler" mode to "Scale With Screen Size", and dial the slider all the way to the "Height" side, so our content only shrinks/crops horizontally, not vertically.
Then we'll add an Image component as a child of the canvas, hosting our bird. We'll set its height to the height of our Canvas Scaler's reference resolution, and its width generously wide, then tick the Image component's "Preserve Aspect" box to keep the right aspect ratio.
Right-aligning the Image within the Canvas and setting its X anchors and pivot to 0.85 seems to do a pretty good job of centering the bird as the aspect ratio gets narrower, and centering the image as a whole when the aspect ratio is wide. That means it's going to position itself so the point 85% along the image's width maps to 85% across the canvas's width.
Here's a gif showing how the camera framing of the image shifts as the aspect ratio of the game window changes:

Note that, being in UI, this will typically draw over objects in the 3D scene. So if you're making a UI-based game / app, you'll want to arrange your foreground elements in the canvas (using Image components), not in the 3D scene (with SpriteRenderer components), so they're drawn on top.
You can stack UI behind 3D content, but it's a little fiddly to get right, and a topic for another question if that turns out to be something you need.
And here are the full settings I used:


